# kafka ZkUtils Compile time error

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

```
import kafka.utils.{TestUtils, ZKStringSerializer, ZkUtils}
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.{ZkClient, ZkConnection}
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils._

var zkUtils: ZkUtils = _   
//val zkConnection= new ZkConnection(zkConn)
//zkClient = new ZkClient(zkConn,5000,5000,ZKStringSerializer)
//val zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, zkConnection, false)
val (zkClient, zkConnection) = ZkUtils.createZkClientAndConnection(
  zkConn, sessionTimeoutMs, connectionTimeoutMs)
zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, zkConnection, false)
```

I am trying to create a ZkUtils object but facing issues. My Gradle build is successful but when I try to run the test file, face the below issues

Error:(27, 16) not found: type ZkUtils
  var zkUtils: ZkUtils = _
Error:(44, 44) value createZkClientAndConnection is not a member of object kafka.utils.ZkUtils
    val (zkClient, zkConnection) = ZkUtils.createZkClientAndConnection(
Error:(46, 20) not found: type ZkUtils
     zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, zkConnection, false)

I have the following dependencies in my gradle build file as well.

compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: '0.10.2.1', classifier:'test'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: '0.10.2.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: '0.10.2.1', classifier:'test'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: '0.10.2.1'

I have these imports as well in my file. Can anyone tell me whats going wrong here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error message seems to imply that you're using some old version of `kafka.utils.ZkUtils` [prior to v0.9](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/utils/ZkUtils.scala), which doesn't have method `createZkClientAndConnection` defined in object `ZkUtils`.

Comment: Well even if I dont use that method and uncomment the commented lines in the code. I will still get the error as " not found: type ZkUtils zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, zkConnection, false)"

Comment: @HelloWorld 0.10.x versions have "createZkClientAndConnection" method available